# Create trigger base on time and insert to another table

Tags: sql-server, trigger

How to create a trigger for my case?

1. A table has columns id, value and datetime.
2. I want to create a trigger; when data is more than 1 week old move it to another table (historical); data less than 1 week old will be remain in the current table (live table)

Comment: I think maybe a trigger is not the right technique to achieve this. Another way that might make more sense is to create an SQL script which moves the data then make a SQL Agent job which runs on a schedule (weekly, daily, hourly, ...) and executes your script.

Comment: can you give an example of this script?

Comment: Yeah, trigger is the wrong technology for this. A scheduled job is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

It could go something like this. Grab the old data into a temp table. Insert it into the history table then delete from the live table. I'll leave the error handling as an exercise for the reader.

```
Begin Transaction archive

Select id, value, [datetime]
  Into #historical_to_archive
  From Live_Table
  Where [datetime] < DateAdd(Day, -7, GetDate());

Insert Into History_Table (id, value, [datetime])
Select id, value, [datetime]
  From #historical_to_archive;

Delete
  From Live_Table
  Where id In (Select id From #historical_to_archive);

Drop Table #historical_to_archive;

Commit Transaction archive
```

Answer (score 1):

For 2005+ using `OUTPUT` clause

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN
Delete
  From Live_Table
OUTPUT d.id,d.value,d.[datetime] into History_Table 
  Where [datetime] < DateAdd(Day, -7, GetDate());
COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRAN
SELECT @@ERROR
END CATCH
```